# Change the URL depending on the QueryString [JSP/Servlet]

Tags: jsp, url, servlets, mapping, query-string

I apologise if the question is poorly worded... I wasn't quite sure how to go about asking.

How would I go about changing the URL depending on the query string, for example:

If someone clicks a link for some lovely carrots, instead of the URL being foo.com/product.jsp?id=2 it would be foo.com/product/some-lovely-carrots.

I tried adding mapping to web.xml, but I don't think I'm going the right way about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "pretty URL" or "friendly URL". Basically, you'd need to create a filter or maybe a front controller servlet to achieve the job. Assuming that you go the filter direction, it would look something like as following:

```
private Map<String, String> mapping;

@Override
public void init() {
    mapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapping.put("/product/some-lovely-carrots", "/product.jsp?id=2");
    // ...

    // You can of course also fill this map based on some XML config file or
    // even a database table.
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
    String target = mapping.get(path);

    if (target != null) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher(target).forward(req, res);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

Map this filter on an URL pattern of `/*` and change the link as follows

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/product/some-lovely-carrots">Some lovely carrots</a>
```